# How to make Widgets background transparent in Qt

Tags: qt, qt4, symbian

I am building an App in which I had given background to my mainWindow only and all other widgets are used without any background, but when I run the app they are not 100% transparent they are somewhat translucent, is there any way to make them 100 % transparent so that only foreground can appear with no background hint.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Could you post the code you are using to get transparancy at the moment? If you say that you get "something translucent" I think that you created a tool window which is not what you really want.

A really transparent main window could be achieved by removing the title bar (give the QWidget constructor Qt::FramelessWindowHint as second parameter - WindowFlags), draw everything in the widget that should be transparent in a uncommon color (like 255,0,255) and then cut it off.

A very primitive example of cutting off parts of a QWidget:

```
QBitmap b(100, 100);
b.fill(Qt::black);
setMask(b);
```

QBitmap must be black on that pixels that shall be visible and white on that are not. In this example just the 100,100 area starting at 0,0 will be visible, the rest of your window will be invisible.

Comment: As you can see in the screen shot, child widget is showing its own background, but I haven't given any to it, When I design this screen I left the set Style Sheet balnk.